# How do I do a customised LVM install of Ubuntu 18.04.1 Desktop LTS?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, lvm

Please can someone tell me how to do a custom LVM install of Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Desktop. I have RTFM and it didn't help me.
I've hit multiple problems trying to install it:

A) Trying to do a 'default' LVM install does not do what I want

B) Trying to do a *cough* partial default LVM install by cancelling, and re-starting with a custom LVM install fails as the LVM volumes on the new drive are 'grabbed' by the DVD Ubuntu on reboot and so cannot be changed.

C) Deleting *cough* the symlinks in /dev/mapper partially started the customised LVM install (I can then delete the LVM partitions), but I couldn't change things; it's like the LVM info is opaque to the installer

D) Booting the DVD, I cannot install either partitionmanager or kvpm ("E: Unable to locate package ...")

Some workable way forward would be really appreciated. I am not familiar with LVM but quite willing to learn.

Comment: You have not described what you are trying to do with LVM.

Comment: I want to define an EFI partition, a swap partition, a root partition, a home partition, and plenty of space left over to allocate later. I expect that it's just the root & home (and spare space?) that will be in the LVM, but maybe others suggest something different.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I did the following:

- Started (but cancelled) a 'standard LVM' install. This creates a basic LVM on the drive
- NB If you then reboot your 'Live CD' DVD, I had problems early on with being unable to do anything with the LVM so created. (These problems may be because I was unfamiliar with LVM.)
- I could see no way to use 'something else' to tweak an LVM install. It would have been helpful for it to give some hints/clues about how to do what I then did ...
- Used variety of `lvremove`, `vgrename`, `lvcreate` to prepare the LVM as I wanted. BTW this included `/`(root), `/home`, `/var`, `/swap`.
- Start install with 'something else' and point various partitions in `/dev/mapper`(?) as I wanted them in the install. To me, this mapping was not intuitive, as it lists many partitions that are irrelevant, and of the relevant ones half the nearly-duplicated lines can't be selected anyway.

So I now have Ubuntu 18.04.1 installed.